# Why do you have to turn off the prop sync when changing the engine rpm?

Tags: aircraft-performance, propeller, aircraft-systems

I understand how prop sync works, I just don't understand why you have to have to turn it off to switch the rpm. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Didn't have to do that on the last prop aircraft I flew; can you provide a reference for an aircraft which requires this?

Comment: @RalphJ I learned to switch it off in a King Air with a Type I Synchrophaser (a Type II does not require it): "The propellers should be manually synchronized before turning the system on. [...] If you change prop RPM, you may need to switch off the prop sync and repeat this process to resync the props." Nonetheless, it would be great if the OP specified the exact aircraft.

Comment: I've answered this previously in regards to why prop sync is required off during takeoff/landing but I suspect this may be different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-FADEC synchrophase systems normally adjust a "slave" propeller, usually No.2 engine, to match the RPM and blade phase of a "master" propeller, usually No. 1 engine.

The only adjusting that is getting done is to the slave propeller's governor, matching its RPM/phase to the master, and there will be a servo unit, typically a torque motor, on that propeller's speed governor that trims the input from that prop's condition lever in the cockpit within a small range.

So when there is a requirement to match RPMs manually before turning synchrophase on, it's because the authority of the slave engine's servo has a limited range. On the Pratt & Whitney PW-120, the setting requirement was only 20 RPM.  If you turn it on with too much differential between left and right propellers, say 50 RPM, the slave propeller's servo may run out of travel trying to match its RPM with the master, and you will run with some RPM differential still in place as the synchrophaser tries to do its thing but can't quite make it.

This will apply to a conventional hydromechanically controlled propeller governor system where the inputs from the cockpit are through linkages to the engine.  If the engine and propeller are controlled through a FADEC system, where the computer has complete control over RPM, you likely won't have this limitation, or at least a much looser one.

Comment: So couldn't you just keep it on the whole flight?

Comment: Except for having to turn it off when making changes, you could, unless there is a specific limitation, like it has to be off for takeoff.  You could turn it on for climb, and flip it off to come back to cruise, then back on again.  Synchphase is mostly a passenger comfort thing.  The oscillating drone drives ppl nuts.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. would it break if you changed rpm with prop sync on?

Comment: No you just won't get them to synch because the servo will just sit at full travel and if that's not enough, the controller will just hold it like that because it's just a dumb box trying to make an internal signal differential go away.